# SimpleXML and foreach

Tags: php, xml-parsing, simplexml

I have some trouble with PHP and XML. If I need to filter a specific parameter from XML source with `FOREACH` and the specific block doesn't exist, the result is empty. But I need show something like this: "No active service".

```
<?php
$data = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<note>
  <to>
    <form>pswA</form>
    <heading>A</heading>
  </to>
  <to>
    <form>pswB</form>
    <heading>A</heading>
  </to>
</note>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);
  foreach ($xml->to as $to){
      if     ($to->form == 'pswA' && $to->heading == 'A'){echo "allow";}
      elseif ($to->form == 'pswA' && $to->heading == 'B'){echo "notallow";}
      elseif ($to->form == 'pswA' && $to->heading == 'C'){echo "block";}
  } // this exist and show (allow / notallow / block)

  foreach ($xml->to as $to){
      if     ($to->form == 'pswC' && $to->heading == 'A'){echo "allow";}
      elseif ($to->form == 'pswC' && $to->heading == 'B'){echo "notallow";}
      elseif ($to->form == 'pswC' && $to->heading == 'C'){echo "block";}
  } // but this is empty... how can I show some echo?
?>
```

Is it possible to show a message when the second `foreach` doesn't exist? More in this example and live preview: https://3v4l.org/GhdRT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a variable to keep track of whether you found an active service.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);
$pswA_found = false;
foreach ($xml->to as $to){
    if     ($to->form == 'pswA' && $to->heading == 'A'){
        echo "allow";
        $pswA_found = true;
    }
    elseif ($to->form == 'pswA' && $to->heading == 'B'){
        echo "notallow";
        $pswA_found = true;
    }
    elseif ($to->form == 'pswA' && $to->heading == 'C'){
        echo "block";
        $pswA_found = true;
    }
}
if (!$pswA_found) {
    echo "No active service for pswA";
}

$pswC_found = false;
foreach ($xml->to as $to){
    if     ($to->form == 'pswC' && $to->heading == 'A'){
        echo "allow";
        $pswC_found = true;
    }
    elseif ($to->form == 'pswC' && $to->heading == 'B'){
        echo "notallow";
        $pswC_found = true;
    }
    elseif ($to->form == 'pswC' && $to->heading == 'C'){
        echo "block";
        $pswC_found = true;
    }
}
if (!$pswC_found) {
    echo "No active service for pswC";
}
```